# Is there a simple way to solve an infinite series when noniterative variables are present? Or would it need to be solved point-by-point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Noniterative variables being spectral variables like x, y, or some other variable that the series is not iterating over.

The motivation for asking arose when I obtained the solution to some PDE (Poisson's equation) within the domain $0\le x,y \le1$ as:

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi} \frac{\sinh\big(n\pi(1-y)\big)}{\sinh(n\pi y)} \sin(n\pi x)$$

and then I asked myself "well that's all well and good that this is the solution, but what good is it if I don't know how to evaluate the series?"

I know series like this can be computed for specific points like $u(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{32}$ using certain techniques (which from the methods I've seen thus far, go into the realm of complex analysis). Points like this allow for simplification of the series making it much easier to solve, however I can't do much with $\sin(n\pi x)$ or the hyperbolic functions present as is.

What I'd like to know, is if there is some eloquent process for evaluating series like these for all x and y in the domain or do I have to evaluate this series 1 point at a time? Or is there a way to reduce the sum to some functional representation similar to how $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)x^{2n+1}}$ (which also has a noniterative variable, x, present) can be reduced to a functional defintion $f(x) = \arctan(x)$?

---

EDIT: Now that I think about it, it would be the same thing as if I had a constant inside of the series. So I could also rewrite the series as:

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n\pi} \frac{\sinh\big(n\pi(1-b)\big)}{\sinh(n\pi b)} \sin(n\pi a)$$

Not that this matters, but it might be a more familiar form for anyone who might have worked on a similar problem to help offer insight.